# How can ESL students improve their pronunciation by using technology?

Tags: resource-request, english, pronunciation

Can ESL students improve their pronunciation by using technology?
Are there any specific applications for pronunciation assessment and  improvement?

Answer (score 1):

This 1½ hour session is designed to assist non-native speakers of English in accent reduction. The session includes a brief overview of the elements of pronunciation, including difficult sounds, stress, rhythm, and intonation. Specific practice techniques for addressing the most common pronunciation problems will be shared, along with a list of technology resources available for further independent practice and self-study: [**Here.**](https://youtu.be/nkQ7lwEWeGA?si=nqYYmhMtIkX43HSr)